# Why is my voltage controlled current source circuit not reaching above 1A?

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, voltage-divider, current-source

I was given a circuit that converts 0-10V to 0-1A using an op amp and a mosfet. The current is driving a solenoid. However, I needed to alter the circuit to provide 0-1.5A using the same voltage range. The circuit has a voltage divider built in before the op amp to scale the voltage from 0-10V to 0-1V. I know that whatever the input voltage is supposed to be in the op amp, it will drive its output and the mosfet to match this. However, when I implemented the voltage divider to produce a 0-1.5V input in order to cause a 0-1.5A output, it will not reach above 1A. I have tried looking up why this occurs and I cannot find anything on the internet about this. Does anyone have any idea why the voltage/current will not reach above 1.5?
Circuit schematic:

[image]

Comment: What resistance is the load? What on resistance is the MOSFET?

Comment: Are you running it from a current-limited power supply?

Comment: According to the data sheet, the on resistance for the IRF630 is 0.4 ohms at Vgs=10V. I will have to check my power supply to see if that is the cause.

Comment: Is this with the solenoid connected? If so, what are its specs (resistance or current at rated voltage)?

Comment: What is the voltage on pin1  of the opamp when the output is at 1Amp?  Is the opamp output already at max?

Comment: What power rating did you use on the 1-ohm resistor?   1 amp across 1 ohm is 1 watt.  This would be a resistor thats about 1/2" long or so.   If you used a more common 1/4 watt, the resistor would get way too hot, causing its value to rise, thus throwing your feedback voltage off.   Just stick your finger on it - If it's hot you need to change it.  If its barely warm, then ignore everything I just said  ;)

Comment: Also, check that your solenoid "ground" is not connected this circuits "ground"... The node marked  "OUT (-)" should definitely not connect to "ground", even if the solenoid has a "(-)" marked on it.   If you know your way around electronics, this comment probably insulted you (sorry!).  If you don't know your way around, this would be a SUPER EASY mistake to make.  Since you have only 1 post, hard to know which person you are   ;)

Comment: The voltage supply is able to output up to 3A, so that is not the issue. When the output of the circuit reaches 1A, the op amp is around 5V. Once it exceeds around 1.1A, the output of the op amp suddenly skyrockets to around 22V, which I am guessing is the max output of the op amp. The 1 ohm resistor is a 5 watt resistor, so it is not that. The solenoid is just connected in parallel to the circuit (between pin 4 and 5), so I don't believe it is connected to any ground. I am not super familiar with electronics, but I am an undergraduate electrical engineering student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out that the solenoid was the reason why the circuit would not reach 1.5A. The resistance of the coil was 15ohms at room temp, but when it heated up at high currents, the resistance would rise to about 22ohms. So, the solenoid was limiting the current. I confirmed that this was the case by attaching a lower resistance solenoid to the circuit, which managed to reach 1.5A no problem.

Comment: Good job and thanks for posting a reply. Don't forget to accept this answer to mark the problem as solved. (You may have to wait a day or so.)